# How to pass an object parameter value to a method of that same object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Forgive me if this is a potential duplicate, however I have been unable to get any resolution from similar questions on this site or elsewhere.

I have created a class with several properties and one method.  The values of the properties are obtained from JSON-P data as individual objects are created.  The method is supposed to take the value of one of those properties, run it through if-else logic and return a value.

The method is not returning a value, and firebug isn't reporting any issues that I can see although I suspect it has something to do with inheritance.  Would you be so kind as to examine the code and suggest possible ways to resolve the issue:

```
function Forecast(temperature, wind, desc, high, low, iconID, date) {
//creates object class "Forecast"
this.temperature = temperature;
this.wind = wind;
this.desc = desc;
this.high = high;
this.low = low;
this.iconID = iconID;
this.date = date;

this.skycon = function pickIcon() {

                var clearSky = [800];
                var partlyCloudy = [801];
                var cloudy = [802, 803, 804];
                var rain = [200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 232, 300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 511, 520, 521, 522, 531];
                var sleet = [611, 612, 615, 616, 906];
                var snow = [600, 601, 602, 620, 621, 622];
                var windy = [900, 901, 902, 905, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962];
                var misty = [701, 741];

                if (clearSky.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.CLEAR_DAY;   
                } else if (partlyCloudy.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY;
                } else if (cloudy.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.CLOUD_DAY;
                } else if (rain.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.RAIN;
                } else if (sleet.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.SLEET;
                } else if (snow.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.SNOW;
                } else if (windy.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.WIND;
                } else if (misty.indexOf(this.iconID) >= 0) {
                    return Skycons.MIST;
                }
            };
};
```

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with inheritance, you're not doing any inheritance in your code.

Comment: You forgot to show us the code that constructs the instances and calls the methods. You need to provide details what input you passed and what the output was and what output you had expected.

Comment: what does not functioning correctly mean? how is it not functioning correctly?

Comment: Could you post the code that is using this object?

Comment: is `pickIcon` a function defined elsewhere or why have you named it as well as assigning it?

Comment: Why did I receive a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.  The code sample above works precisely as expected.  As I am still learning, I neglected to call the method at the appropriate point in the program flow correctly.  I did so successfully like this:

```
skycons.add("icon2", tomorrow.skycon(tomorrow.iconID);
```